# Hangman program finished but i'm still having a few problems( I'm not sure about the array I used to check letters)

Tags: java

```
/*
 * 
 * Hangman.java 
 * The program asks the user to choose a file that is provided. 
 * The program will read one line from the file and the player will guess the word.
 * and then outputs the line, the word will appear using "_".
 * The player will guess letters within the word or guess entire word,
 * if the player guesses correctly the "_" will replaced with the letter guessed. 
 * But, if the player guesses incorrectly the a part of the stickman's body will be added,
 * then the user will be asked to guess again. The user can also enter "!" to guess the entire word,
 * if  the guess correctly they win, but if they guess incorrectly they will be asked to guess again.
 * Once it has finished reading the file, the program outputs the number of guesses.
 */
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
//class name
public class Hangman
{
    static Console c;
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    c = new Console ();  
c.println("Hello, and welcome to Hangman!");
    PrintWriter output;
    String fileName;
//ask user to choose file; file contains words for user to guess
    c.println ("The categories are: cartoons.txt, animals.txt, and food.txt. Which category would you like to choose?");
    fileName = c.readLine ();    
    // R:\\HNMRY\\ICS3U10\\Assignments\\Sumbit your work for marks here\\Frank, Tracy\\+fileName
try {

            /*  Sets up a file reader to read the file passed on the command
               line one character at a time */
            FileReader input = new FileReader(args[0]);

            /* Filter FileReader through a Buffered read to read a line at a
               time */
            BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);

            String line;    // String that holds current file line
            int count = 0;  // Line number of count 

            // Read first line
           line = bufRead.readLine();
            count++;

{
  lineCount++;
  output.println (lineCount + "   " + line);
  line = input.readLine ();
}
            // Read through file one line at time. Print line # and line
           while (line != null){
               c.println(count+": "+line);
                line = bufRead.readLine ();
                count++;
           }

            bufRead.close();

        }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      c.println("File does not exist or could not be found.");
      c.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      c.println("Problem reading file.");
      c.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
final String GUESS_FULL_WORD = "!";

// set integer value for number of letters for the length of the secret word
// set integer value for the number of guesses the user have made. starting at zero.
    int numberofletters, numberofguesses;
    numberofguesses = 0;
// guessletter indicates the letter that the user is guessing
// guessword indicates the word that the user is guessing after typing "!"
// new screen indicates the change made to the screen
// screen is the game screen that contains all the "_"'s
    String guessletter, guessword, newscreen;
    String screen = "";
    numberofletters = SECRET_WORD.length ();

// for every letter there is in the secretword, add a "_" to screen.
    for (int numdashes = 1; numdashes <= numberofletters; numdashes ++)
    {
      screen += "_";
    }

//Array to check letters entered by user 
final int LOW = 'A';  //smallest possible value
final int HIGH = 'Z';  //highest possible value

int[] letterCounts = new int[HIGH - LOW + 1];  
String SECRET_WORD;
char[] guessletter;
int offset;  //array index
// set constants for the secret word and also "!" to guess the full word
final String GUESS_FULL_WORD = "!";
```

// set integer value for number of letters for the length of the secret word
// set integer value for the number of guesses the user have made. starting at zero.
    int numberofletters, numberofguesses;
    numberofguesses = 0;

// guessletter indicates the letter that the user is guessing
// guessword indicates the word that the user is guessing after typing "!"
// new screen indicates the change made to the screen
// screen is the game screen that contains all the "_"'s
    String guessletter, guessword, newscreen;
    String screen = "";
    numberofletters = SECRET_WORD.length ();

```
  /* prompt user for a word */
c.print("Enter a letter: ");
guessletter = c.readLine();
// start guessing!
// keep the user guessing (do while loop) until user types in "!" or the game screen is all filled with letters
// add one to numberofguesses to as a counter for the guesses the user makes
// A string lu(Letters Used) is created to hol the letters the user has already guessed.
String lu;
Boolean canPlay = true; 
    do
    {
    c.println ("(TYPE (!) TO GUESS THE WHOLE MYSTERY WORD!)");
    c.println (screen);
    c.println ("Please guess a letter:  ");
    guessletter = c.readLine ();
    numberofguesses = numberofguesses + 1;
// change user's guessed letter to upper case.
    guessletter = guessletter.toUpperCase ();
// make an index for which space the guessed letter is in the secret word.
    int indexof = SECRET_WORD.indexOf (guessletter);
// if the guessed letter DOES appear in the secret word
// then replace the guessed letter on the corresponding dash on the newscreen
// the dashes that is in front of the corresponding dash and behind it is not changed to the current newscreen.
// the replace the information of the old screen with the new screen.
    if (indexof > -1)
    {
      newscreen = (screen.substring (0,indexof) + guessletter + screen.substring (indexof+1));
      screen = newscreen; 
    }
    }while (GUESS_FULL_WORD.compareTo (guessletter)!= 0 && SECRET_WORD.compareTo (screen) !=0);

// if the screen equals the secret word (the dashes are all replaced with letters)
// then indicate that the user have won.
// also include the secret word and the number of guesses the used have made.
    if (screen.equals (SECRET_WORD))
    {
      c.println ("WOW!! YOU WON!! (:");
      c.println ("The scecret word was..." +SECRET_WORD);
      c.println ("You've guessed the total of " +numberofguesses+ " times");
    }
// if the user enters "!" then
    if (guessletter.equals (GUESS_FULL_WORD))
    {
    c.println (screen);
// allow the user to guess the whole word.
    c.println ("What is the secret word?  ");
    guessword = c.readLine ();
// change the user's guess into upper case
    guessword = guessword.toUpperCase ();

   if (numberofguesses==6)
{
canPlay = false;
Lose();
}
else
/*
* Put man here
          --
          o |
         /|\|
         / \|
         _____
*/
        String man[] = new String[7]
        man[0] = " --\n   |\n   |\n   |\n_____\n";
        man[1] = " --\n o |\n   |\n   |\n_____\n";
        man[2] = " --\n o |\n/  |\n   |\n_____\n";
        man[3] = " --\n o |\n/| |\n   |\n_____\n";
        man[4] = " --\n o |\n/|\\|\n   |\n_____\n";
        man[5] = " --\n o |\n/|\\|\n/  |\n_____\n";
        man[6] = " --\n o |\n/|\\|\n/ \\|\n_____\n";
char g1[] = guess.toCharArray();
        char w2[] = word.toCharArray();
        c.println(man[0]);
        for(int x=0;x<g1.length;x++)
        {
          c.print(g1[x]);
        }
        c.println();

// inside the if-statement...
// if the user's guess (full word) match with the secret word then
// indicate that the user have won.
// also include the secret word and also the number of guesses the user have made.
    if (guessword.compareTo (SECRET_WORD) ==0)
    {
      c.println ("WOW!! YOU'VE GUESSED IT!! (:");
      c.println ("The scecret word was..." +SECRET_WORD);
      c.println ("You've guessed the total of " +numberofguesses+ " times");
    }
// if the user's guess (full word) does not match with the secret word then
// indicate that the user have lost.
// also include the secret word and also the number of guesses the user have made
    else
    {
      c.println ("OOPS...! YOU LOSE!! ):");
      c.println ("The scecret word was..." +SECRET_WORD);
      c.println ("You've guessed the total of " +numberofguesses+ " times");
    }
    }
```

```
**7 errors found:**
File: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java  [line: 166]
Error: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java:166: not a statement
File: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java  [line: 166]
Error: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java:166: ';' expected
File: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java  [line: 166]
Error: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java:166: not a statement
File: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java  [line: 166]
Error: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java:166: ';' expected
File: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java  [line: 166]
Error: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java:166: not a statement
File: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java  [line: 166]
Error: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java:166: ';' expected
File: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java  [line: 203]
Error: H:\My Documents\Dr. Java\Hangman.java:203: reached end of file while parsing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a bare minimum, you need a semicolon here:

```
String man[] = new String[7]
```

Change this to:

```
String man[] = new String[7];
```

That's the problem on line 166. The problem on line 203 *may* be fixed by that or it may be indicative of the absence of a closing brace `}` (or simply mismatched braces) somewhere in your code.

Comment: I love how it says that in the errors, but he still needed to ask us.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
        String man[] = new String[7]
```

needs a `;` at the end.

Also the `else` statement a couple of lines before that doesn't have curly braces after it.

And what is `Lose();`?  Looks like a function call to me, but you don't have a corresponding function.

Answer (score 0):

you should compile every time you make a change to the code (and fix those errors) so you won't have to deal with a dozen syntax errors before you can start debugging

```
String man[] = new String[7]
```

is missing a `;`

the else before it is missing a `{` and there are several `}` missing at the end of the file

btw indent your code properly this is a huge help in finding mismatched braces